# Why does this ASP.NET Core Docker Image contain this 'extra' "FROM build AS publish" multistage build step?

Tags: docker

I'm trying to understand what the point of this line in this Docker file is:

```
FROM build AS publish
```

If I remove it, the build fails with `=> ERROR FROM docker.io/library/publish:latest` so it's obviously needed, but I don't understand why.

It looks to me as though it's unnecessary because `publish` is an alias for the same image as `build`. The WORKDIR isn't changed - so what is this line facilitating that is not possible without? Apologies if this is not a clear question, some of these concepts are new to me.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0.5-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0.202-buster-slim AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY NuGet.Config /
COPY ["Something.Api.Common/Something.Api.Common.csproj", "Something.Api.Common/"]
COPY ["Something.Api.Core.WebApi/Something.Api.Core.WebApi.csproj", "Something.Api.Core.WebApi/"]
COPY ["Something.Api.Core.Domain/Something.Api.Core.Domain.csproj", "Something.Api.Core.Domain/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Something.Api.Core.WebApi/Something.Api.Core.WebApi.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Something.Api.Core.WebApi"
RUN dotnet build "Something.Api.Core.WebApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Something.Api.Core.WebApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

...
```

Answer (score 3):

Answering this my self now. Changing the copy step allows me to remove the 'extra' line. I hadn't understood the `--from` argument!

```
COPY --from=build /app/publish .
```